# Unwanted space when zooming (div tag)

Tags: css, image, html, layout

I have a div background image in the bottom right corner of my page. The problem is when I zoom out there is a small space that appear between it and the right and bottom of the page. I'm not sure why it's doing this.

I'm still kind of new at this, but any help you can give, I would really appreciate.

Below is an image showing the changes as I zoom, and my relevant html/css

[image]

This is my html

```
<div id="bottom_bar">
<p>COPYRIGHT DAVIDMORRIS © 2014 | <a href="index.html">NEWSLETTER</a> | <a href="index.html">FACEBOOK</a>
<span class="right">DESIGN: PROMISE LAND PARTNERS</span>
</p>
</div>


<a href="index.html">
<div id="portfolio"></div>
</a>

</body>
```

and This is the CSS

```
#portfolio {
    background-image:  url(img/portfoliopanel.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 117px;
    width: 198px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 27px;
    right: 0%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#portfolio:hover {
    background-image: url(img/portfolio_pushed.png);
}
```

Comment: can you create a sample on jsfiddle with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this way is useful for you, here i mentioned .nauture_image class  DIV is that nature image background div, you just use that parent of #portfolio Div lyk this:

HTML

```
<div class="nature_image">
     <a href="index.html">
          <div id="portfolio"></div>
    </a>
</div>


<div id="bottom_bar">
<p>COPYRIGHT DAVIDMORRIS © 2014 | <a href="index.html">NEWSLETTER</a> | <a href="index.html">FACEBOOK</a>
<span class="right">DESIGN: PROMISE LAND PARTNERS</span>
</p>
</div>

</body>
```

then use the css lyk below, u should give position:relative and mention specific height for parent div( .nature_image div), then also give postion: absolute and bottom:0; for child #portfolio ID div

CSS:

```
.nature_image{ 
    background-image:  url(img/nauture_image_bg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 480pxpx;
    width: 100%px;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#portfolio {
    background-image:  url(img/portfoliopanel.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 117px;
    width: 198px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I believe this is usefull for you,

Thanks

Senthil